# Swift : Simplifying Nested Firebase Fetching/Queries

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was curious to know if there is a way to simplify my Firebase DB queries.

Also, what are some best practices to follow when making pull requests.

Ive noticed the more complex my hierarchical structure gets from adding children results in extremely strenuous and long queries within my code.

Here is an example of a query within my application:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you find yourself needing complex queries, it most likely means that your data isn't properly structured.
In your case, your structure needs to be normalized (flattened).

The following modification should make your queries simpler:

```
{
  "listings": {
     "listing_key_1": {
        "timestamp": "2017 10 19 07:49:38"
     },
     "listing_key_2": {
        "timestamp": "2017 10 19 05:30:02"
     },
     ...
  },

  "AircraftHouseRules": {
     "listing_key_1": {
         "Availability": "",
         ...
     },
     "listing_key_2": {
         "Availability": "",
         ...
     }
  },

  "BasicInfo": {
     "listing_key_1": {
         "ModelPlane": "",
         ...
     },
     "listing_key_2": {
         "ModelPlane": "",
         ...
     }
  },
  ...
}
```

I don't get what you mean by "pull requests". If you mean observing or simply reading the data, it's pretty straightforward. All you need in your case is a `listing` id/key to gain direct access to its data (`AircraftHouseRules`, `BasicInfo`, `DetailedInformation`, etc...).

If you want the reverse (to get the key of a listing through, let's say, its `TypeOfPlane`), you can do the following query

```
// NOTE: Untested code - just for illustrative purposes
let queryRef = Database().database.reference.child("BasicInfo").queryOrdered(byChild: "TypeOfPlane").queryEqual(to: "some type")

queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with { snapshot in
    if let listings = snapshot.value as? [String : Any] { 
      // all retrieved listings with TypeOfPlane == "some type"
    } 
})
```

**Tips**

You should always [avoid nesting structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) to avoid downloading unnecessary data and hindering performance. In the screenshot you posted, you have up to 8 levels of nested data. With the modification above you can halve those levels easily.

You should also consider replacing all array structures (like the ones under `ImageRef`) with key-value pairs as [arrays can be evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38421497/3551916).

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations. I will make changes.